# What to add to magic to make magical fights more understandable?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems, fight

In both movies and written stories its somewhat easy to see or describe the balance in a fight. By showing/describing size, weapons or their skill you can set the differences between the fighters apart. On top of that you can use our understanding of the physical world to interpret damage done. A bruise, cut, bullethole or broken bone all result in the viewer/reader having an understanding of what is happening and how well the participants are doing*.

Magical fights on the other hand are terrible at displaying the differences during a fight or how the fight is progressing. Energy flashes around, shields/deflections work or dont work based more on character importance than seeming skill, wether a hit kills or not is more plotbased than anything else and there is no clear indication why a caster might pick one spell over another.

This is somewhat understandable. The amount of magical power left to a person is unclear and what that means is often not described. Spells in movies often turn into magical guns that fire almost instantly but with less reliability than bullets when they hit and in written stories the description of how a spell really works is done for a select few, if at all.

So my question becomes: "what needs to be added to a magic system to make magical fights understandable, *without* limiting magical styles?"

The most magical styles this can be added to, the better. So it should be just as applicable to magical fight in LOTR** if we were to follow a magic user as main character in a fight as to Harry Potter or one of Brandon Sanderson's magic systems.

*assuming the creators bothered to create an understandable narrative to the fight.

**LOTR from what I understand and read has a soft magical system since magic is part of the background more than the direct story. Like Gandalf saying he fought a Balrog with Magic and in the books going essentially off-screen to do his magic rather than having an exhaustive description of the lightshow.

Comment: Is this a worldbuilding question or a writing one? It seems to be about finding ways of communicating ideas with the audience/readership that are understandable, not per se about worldbuilding.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. While the question is not explicitly worldbuilding, it can be answered using Worldbuilding methods. In particular by designing a suitable magic system.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I originally wanted to post it in the writing section but I think the problem is a missing factor in magic, a tangibility that misses and makes it hard to create an understandable combat narrative that does not conclude in pretty much "well this guy was more powerful this time".

Comment: Alright, I've retracted the close-vote and may write an answer.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you are looking for some visible and intuitive indicators for damage done by magic? I also want to point out that there are some cultural differences in depictions of fights. For example, Chinese films and books routinely use spitting blood as an indicator of internal injuries, but it is highly uncommon in the Western tradition. Do you want to take into consideration this type of conventions? Or are looking for something more grounded in real-world physics and biology?

Comment: @Otkin the tradition for spitting blood is what I am seeking to create, except for magic. I dont want to just be able to spot the damage the magic has done, be able to show/describe in an understandable and universal way the state magic users and their targets are in and give the viewers/readers an understanding of when/how someone is going to win or lose, even if the magic setting is a soft one with undefined rules. Magic fights almost universally resolve in "and now X has won" without a clear indication why this time it finished the target and before it didnt, or how the battle got so far.

Comment: @Demigan One more question. Do you want to abide by the convention of the limited point of view and perspective or are you fine with an omniscient narrator? In other words, is it fine with you if you have to switch from one character to another, sometimes multiple times, during the fight?

Comment: @Otkin since its hard to constantly switch perspectives in writing during a battle and even harder to show those perspectives in movie form it would need to be useful for a single perspective.

Comment: This should help you Sanderson has some great guidelines for writing a magic system. https://www.google.com/search?q=sanderson+writing+magic&oq=sanderson+writing+magic&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3376j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 and https://coppermind.net/wiki/Sanderson%27s_Laws_of_Magic

Comment: @John when I first heard of Branderson's law I thought "but that's obvious, everyone already knew and wrote like that right?". It was a natural improvement of my earlier stories to use magic as an additional natural law for some people rather than a get-your-plot-or-character-to-do-what-you-want-whenever-you-want freecard. However the law does nothing for my question. The Stormlight saga has no indication of the amount of metal in the opposition or their relative strength, Elantris has no indication of power limits etc. His laws do not provide the framework necessary, which is why its missing.

Comment: @Demigan he has three laws not 1, which is why I linked his lecture on writing, his second is most relevant, what magic can't do is more informative than what it can do.   You will never have those things in the same way no movie going audience knows how debilitating being stabbd is, or how long it takes being set on fire to kills you. you could get them across but only by boring your audience with hours of tangential lessons. what you can do is maintain consistency, sudden changes in power can't actually be sudden (surprising) of they feel like ass pulls.

Comment: @John none of the laws give a sufficient system to understand how a battle is going. The audience might not know how debilitating a knife stab is in detail, but you can make believable debilitations based on where and how the knife hits. You cant do that directly with Sanderson's laws, which is why his magic systems suffer from the exact same problem.

Comment: @Demigan you can do the same thing with magic, if it removes a limb it is obviously worse than something that leaves a scratch or minor burn. how exhausted a spellcaster is is no different than depicting how exhausted a boxer is. It sounds like you need to describe what you want your magic system to do  in some detail before this can be answered. How soft a magic system do you want, the more concrete the effects and the more limitation the more obvious you can make it.

Comment: @John since all magic systems so far mentioned do not use that I'm going to need something more concrete. If you do not understand the question you should ask for clarification.

Comment: @Demigan I can think of half a dozen that use that, sympathy magic in the name of the wind, avatar the last airbender, fullmetal alchemist, dark sun, just off the top of my head. the limitations of a magic system are what allow it ot be realistic, if magic can do literally anything then making it realistic is all but impossible. this is why there is a distinction between hard and soft magic systems. this may help you https://habitwriting.com/hard-magic-vs-soft-magic/

Comment: @John with "that" I meant "make the magic system during combat understandable" not "make it realistic/concrete". And "understandable" does not mean "I know what moves cause water or fireballs to erupt" but a way to gauge how the battle progresses.

Comment: @Demigan a magic system has ot be concrete to be understandable, soft magic systems are not understandable and that is why characters can pull stuff out of their butt, Gandalf for example is a very soft system so there is little reason to show a fight since the audience will have no idea what is going on, even the author did not have a good idea of how it was resolved. it is not know what move makes a fireball, it is knowing what making a fireball costs, what if can and can't do , what getting hit by one can do, that is what lets you gauge a fight, rules are what us understand something.

Comment: @John I want a system that does not require intricate knowledge of the magic system to be understandable. Nepene Nep's system of a visual glow which indicates magical power/prowess/status would let the audience know how the fight progresses without the need to know each individual spell. This is something missing from virtually all magic systems. I'll likely accept that one as the answer unless a better one comes along. I'd prefer a system that would only indicate the situation of the mage when spotted, not have the magical glow tip off people to the mage.

Comment: @Demigan OK I completely misunderstood what you wanted, I though you were focused on the audience understanding the FIGHT, if you just want an MP bar, glow is used in several systems including sandersons shard bearers, bleach used how intact magical clothing was, a few have used actual floating MP bars, there was an old anime that used hair length, sanderson again in white sand uses hydration, several sources have used elemental masters by showing how much of their "element is left" water, fire, paper, ect. I remember another using the size of the persons shadow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131936/discussion-between-demigan-and-john).

Answer (score 7):

## Spot failures

In a lot of systems, the magic succeeding or failing is binary. It succeeds or it fails, and that's that.

What works to make magical items more visible is having the shields and protections fail more visibly. So, when a person is running low, or the attacks are especially powerful, have the shield break in parts. It cracks, or a hole appears, and some of attack leaks through the shield. This may injure the person holding the shield, or stuff around them.

Star Trek has a similar system, with their consoles exploding when shields get low.

## Eldritch glows.

Offensive spells and buffs can't have spot failures as easily. So, what they need is to glow in an eldritch way.

When something depletes them, they glow less brightly, and a weaker mage can't make as much glowing.

If it's darkness you can have the reverse, with a more powerful shadow when the spell is cast.

Comment: It's a good point, and works especially well for visual media. For words-media you have even more options since you can describe the subjective experiences of the casters, rather than just what it looks like.

Comment: In addition to cracks or failures, you can also effect the defending wizard's footing.  So, if the counter-spell holds but he is pushed back a bit, You know it was a heavy hit.  If he is not killed but flies across the room: you know he barely survived the hit.  Star Trek rules apply here: The more people fly around the room, the harder you were just hit.

Answer (score 7):

**Three Examples.**

**Lord of the rings:** There are no magical duels here. There is a scene where Gandalf fights the Balrog, but the reader is not meant to have a grasp of exactly how the fight is progressing. All we know for certain is that Galdalf is getting angrier and angrier

[image]

and that means he is losing the fight. The specifics of what spells they are casting is unclear, because the other characters don't know either. Instead the fight is meant to evoke a sense of "wow these two guys are super powerful wizards and it is dangerous to stay here". In the movie this is obvious because of all the collateral damage caused by the duel.

**Harry Potter:** In some scenes the wands work essentially like a gun. The author spent time out of combat explaining how the spells work. We know that when Harry hits with the Disarming spell that he has won the fight. Likewise if he is hit with the Excruciating Curse he has lost. Some spells just make a big hole in the target. So Harry is losing if his cover is destroyed, or he has to run out of cover, or if he is hit on the arm and cannot aim properly et cetera.

**Eragon:** Spellcasters have a reserve of energy. The author goes into great length about how much the characters have left in their body and or the storage gems on their belt. There is also great detail on psychic duels that give an impression of how powerful the opponent is even though we are not told their energy level explicitly. So Eragon is losing when the enemy stabs him with psychic tendrils and he can barely resist, or when the magic gems on his belt are almost empty.

**Main Point:** Make the magic system consistent. Either (i) have a set list of spells that you stick to, or (ii) have an unlimited number of spells but with consistent rules for creating new ones. Make sure the reader understands the spells and/or rules. Spend time developing them out of combat. Include (a) what the spells do and (b) how difficult they are to cast. Then define the opponent's strength in terms of this. Wow he deflected my lvl 6 fireball with a single twitch of his eyebrow! He must be really strong!

You can also (iii) use soft magic to evoke a sense of wonder, and never specify exactly how it works. Usually this is safe for creating problems for the characters, but is unsatisfying if soft magic comes out of nowhere and solves problems.

Answer (score 4):

I think one of the possible ways to approach your problem is this.

**1. Establish points of reference**

This means showing and to some extent explaining the magic outside of the combat situation. The purpose of this step is to show:

- the effects of magic;
- the cost of magic (is it easy to perform, does it leave the mage exhausted, can it be used habitually or is there some special conditions that have to be met, etc.);
- theoretical damage;
- the magic learning/training process (in addition to information about skills, this also creates some references for understanding mastery levels).

These points of reference can be established in many different ways and do not have to involve the protagonist. For example, the devastating damage of some spells can be inferred from the aftermath of their use. Or we can see some minor characters training. Or hear some dialogue between random observers explaining some finer points of magic.

**2. Combat situation: Physically observable indicators of fight progress**

***a. Effects of magic on the surrounding environment***

If there is some surrounding environment, it can be used to visually demonstrate the power of magic and its effects. By comparing the condition of the environment with the condition of the fighters the audience can get some idea about the fight progress, the combatants' abilities, and power levels.

For example, one of the mages may be able to level mountains with their magic. You can show how a mountain ceases to exist, but the opponent still looks unfazed and unscathed.

***b. Effects of magic on combatants***

There are two sides to this: Effects associated with magic (for example, being frozen, being set on fire, etc.) and effects associated with magic use (tiredness, sweating, etc.)

If one side can affect the physical condition of the other -- freeze them, for example, -- but the other side is incapable of doing so despite using similar magic, we can infer who is stronger. The recovery time (how much time does it take to 'unfreeze' oneself) also gives some idea about the balance of powers.

The extent of the received damage can be demonstrated by improper balance, paleness, facial expressions, bleeding, reduced speed, slower reaction time, etc. It does not have to be different from non-magical combat. The additional benefit is that these things are more or less intuitive and do not have to be explained.

Difficulties associated with magic use can manifest as paleness, strained facial expressions, rigid poses, tiredness, excessive sweating, and so on. These can be used to show that the fight is hard or that one side is at disadvantage.

***c. Magic interactions***

Whose magic is stronger? Can one magic nullify or restrict other magic? Is it a clash with a big boom? Or maybe one magic can ignore and flow through the other magic?

This is basically how magical phenomena affect and interact with each other. The exact implementation depends on a particular magical system.

***d. The timing***

How long did the fight last? Did it require special preparations or extensive planning? Did the combatants require rest and/or healing afterwards?

I think it is rather self-explanatory. Longer fights are usually tougher fights. And fights that require long preparations and long recovery periods are even tougher fights.

***e. The number of people involved***

Is it a one-on-one fight? Or is it a classical raid with a group of people attacking a boss? Does the composition of a team matter?

All of these are indicators of the fight difficulty and combatants' power. You can also use failed attempts to defeat someone as reference points for power.

***3. Combat situation: Inner thoughts***

If the narrative has access to the inner thoughts of characters, they can also be used to describe the fight progress and balance of power. This is a bit outside of the scope of the WB.SE, so I am not going to talk about this in detail.

The main idea is that the inner thoughts, character's motivation, resolve, emotions, etc. can also be used as indicators of the fight progress. It is also a good way to introduce explanations for combat mechanics, strategy, and tactics.

---

This answer is by necessity very general. Please feel free to ask for clarifications or elaborations.

---

P.S. I think you might be interested in reading some xianxia novels (Chinese fantasy). They use a different set of conventions compared to Western literature and a lot of them (especially, so-called stallion [harem] novels) feature very long and detailed combat scenes.

Answer (score 3):

### Time and resource investment

Any magic system where someone can just snap a finger and produce the equivalent of a countryside-leveling effect without preparing anything is either too powerful for a story to be interesting or is describing someone who is basically the definition of a god at that point. Make it so that, depending on the amount of time and resources someone invested into something magical, magical things would then be more or less powerful accordingly.

I generally measure the power of the magic in settings as 'amount of sword swings'. If it were me I'd allow my mages to do small things on the fly with a swipe of a hand like a cantrip that affects them about as much as physically swinging or blocking with a sword would, fire bolt the size of an arrow, ray of snow, a very brief shield that is only able to stop cantrip-level magic like the firebolt or slingshot-level physical attacks.

Then I'd allow them to do bigger things based on the amount of time and resources they've invested into their preparation beforehand. This could be anything from scrolls to enchanted items or larger circle-based or 'charge-up' magic.

If I were to allow them more powerful magic by measure of sword swings I'd ask myself, "How much energy should an entire minute of sword swinging delivered in one instance be?" and then create the magic accordingly with the appropriate backlash toward the mage using it. I guarantee you most people would get pretty tired after swinging around a sword for an entire minute at a 1 swing per second rate. You can have more longer-lasting and more powerful mages through this by having the mage be more physically fit as well so not only do they need to devote themselves mentally they need to be devote themselves physically as well to get the most out of their magic.

Items or other things performing the magic instead of the mage would also need an amount of investment from the mage before the battle, storing the time and resources into a powerful single-use tool, so they'd need to be careful with their pre-prepared items. Sure you can carry a lot of fireball scrolls if you dedicate storage or harnesses for them but you can only carry so much. This can limit the power of mages by their physical carrying capacity and ability to quickly be able to access their items. Once all of the scrolls or wands are used up then they're back to cantrips. I'd make it so that the larger the item the more power it can store and so you're then left with the option of having an entire staff's capacity be used in one big explosion or many tiny explosions, but at the end of the day it'd be up to you as the writer to keep in mind how much juice in the tank a person has left and not give them any sort of plot armour and continue blasting things off when they actually have nothing left.

Answer (score 2):

**Brock and Misty**

[image]

Every time something new happens cut to Brock and Misty on the sidelines.

Brock is the one on the right with the spiky hair and lines for eyes. Brock has a lot of knowledge about <s>Pokémon</s> magic so he will tell us the name of the spells and how powerful they are and how hard they are to cast.

Misty is the one on the left with the red hair, egg-baby, and big tall sparkly eyes. Misty also knows about <s>Pokémon</s> magic but she is more of a people person, so she will tell us which of the <s>trainers</s> mages is winning and the correct feelings to have.

Answer (score 1):

**A mana-bar as a magic aura**

My inspiration comes from the nen of Hunter X Hunter.

The mages have an aura, which is their available Magic. Its size determine their mana pool. Its shape determine how they use their magic. Its color determine the mastery they have reached (like belts in martial arts).

This way you see easily who is stronger, who has enough energy to continue and what kind of magic they prefer/know (useful to have a meta for magic duels).

Answer (score 0):

**Don't add, subtract**

Consider The Force in Star Wars. There are a lot of things Jedi/Sith *can* do with The Force, and a lot of variety if you look at everything a Jedi does across all films, games, books, etc. But in the context of a single fight/scene, there usually isn't.

Admittedly, I stopped watching the new films a few years ago, so there is probably a dumpster fire of new stuff, but let's just consider the first 6 films.

Common effects of The Force:

- Telekinesis (grabbing a weapon across the room, choking, unnatural jumping)
- Lightning
- Persuasion (not really used in combat)

There is a lot of interesting action that arises just from combining these elements in variations. In principle, Jedi could probably shoot icebolts or all kinds of stuff, but sometimes less is more.

Do you need 15 types of <s>Pokémon</s> magic, or can you tell the story with 3?